# ¿Por que mi arbol binario no imprime todos los valores que le inserto?

Tags: python, árboles-binarios

Estoy haciendo un árbol binario mediante recursividad. Por el momento tiene una función para insertar un valor dentro de este, y otra para que se devuelvan todos los valores en orden de menor a mayor. Luego creo una lista de 100 números aleatorios entre 1 y 1000, y después los imprimo. Ahora los inserto en el árbol binario, y los muestro para ver si se devuelven de menor a mayor. Ese seria el resultado esperado, y este el obtenido:

[125, 561, 687, 173, 587, 23, 938, 779, 771, 805, 863, 694, 564, 631, 215, 713, 336, 480, 70, 594, 593, 430, 630, 677, 707, 903, 827, 194, 289, 586, 212, 978, 302, 511, 927, 326, 795, 315, 40, 897, 736, 118, 392, 730, 198, 523, 988, 716, 131, 622, 926, 634, 923, 119, 184, 30, 729, 481, 50, 326, 531, 692, 841, 134, 99, 915, 117, 438, 763, 538, 119, 935, 227, 677, 280, 712, 245, 614, 372, 142, 399, 20, 958, 714, 947, 586, 981, 532, 920, 462, 756, 108, 917, 80, 632, 501, 237, 250, 393, 652]
*lista de 100 números*

80

652

125 
*en teoría esta debería ser la lista de 100 números ordenados*

```
import random as r


class node:
    """represents a node containing 1 or 0 values in a binary tree."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.val = None 

    def sort_val(self, val):
        """Inserts the selected value in the correct node"""

        if self.val == None:
            self.val = val

        elif val < self.val:
            self.left = node()
            self.left.sort_val(val)

        elif val == self.val:
            pass

        elif val > self.val:
            self.right = node()
            self.right.sort_val(val)

    def show_tree(self):
        """Shows the value of the selected node and all its childs sorted."""

        if self.left != None:
            self.left.show_tree()

        if self.right != None:
            self.right.show_tree()

        if self.val != None:
            print(self.val)


numlist = []

for i in range(100):
    i = r.randint(1,1000)
    numlist.append(i)

print(numlist)

root = node()

for num in numlist:
    root.sort_val(num)

root.show_tree()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El principal problema lo tienes en:

```
elif val < self.val:
    self.left = node()
```

solo debes instanciar un nuevo nodo si `self.left` es `None`. Lo mismo para el nodo derecho. Si contiene ya un nodo no debes reasignarle otro nuevo o te cargas todo el algoritmo ya que terminarás con solo la raíz y un nodo izquierdo y uno derecho a lo sumo (por eso te imprime solo tres números, la raíz y sus dos nodos hijos, los cuales no tienen hijos por lo comentado).

Por otro lado, para imprimir correctamente el árbol (ordenado) debes cambiar el orden en el que llamas a `print` en `show_tree`, debe estar entre ambos condicionales y no al final para que primero recorra e imprima todos los nodos izquierdos y luego los derechos.

En `sort_val` el condicional `elif val == self.val` no es incorrecto pero es superfluo, no tiene utilidad alguna.

Como nota, para objetos singleton como es `None` (solo existe una instancia del mismo en cada intérprete) la forma correcta (y eficiente) de comparar
no es usando el operador de igualdad/desigualdad (`=`/`!=`) sino el operador de identidad (`is`/`is not`). Por otro lado, las clase (node) se nombran usando CamelCase [por convención (ver PEP-8)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) para diferenciarlas de atributos, variables, funciones o módulos.

Tu código puede quedar:

```
import random as r


class Node:
    """represents a node containing 1 or 0 values in a binary tree."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.val = None

    def sort_val(self, val):
        """Inserts the selected value in the correct node"""

        if self.val is None:
            self.val = val

        elif val < self.val:
            if self.left is None:
                self.left = Node()
            self.left.sort_val(val)

        elif val > self.val:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = Node()
            self.right.sort_val(val)

    def show_tree(self):
        """Shows the value of the selected node and all its childs sorted."""
        if self.left:
            self.left.show_tree()
        print(self.val)
        if self.right:
            self.right.show_tree()


num_list = [r.randint(1, 1000) for _ in range(100)]
print(num_list)

root = Node()
for num in num_list:
    root.sort_val(num)

root.show_tree()
```

Ejemplo de salida:

```
[665, 160, 305, 317, 579, 467, 941, 805, 199, 212, 292, 401, 703, 180, 461, 251, 355, 658, 79, 548, 514, 580, 395, 624, 746, 507, 125, 976, 475, 203, 620, 918, 149, 955, 832, 591, 106, 744, 479, 969, 667, 11, 284, 792, 43, 311, 259, 54, 505, 512, 628, 131, 773, 899, 763, 227, 646, 526, 391, 487, 394, 492, 868, 339, 955, 168, 57, 24, 204, 419, 875, 71, 129, 320, 559, 188, 314, 638, 970, 572, 221, 619, 976, 563, 343, 712, 923, 35, 387, 479, 22, 352, 889, 232, 961, 814, 223, 459, 429, 221]
11
22
24
35
43
54
57
71
79
106
125
129
131
149
160
168
180
188
199
203
204
212
221
223
227
232
251
259
284
292
305
311
314
317
320
339
343
352
355
387
391
394
395
401
419
429
459
461
467
475
479
487
492
505
507
512
514
526
548
559
563
572
579
580
591
619
620
624
628
638
646
658
665
667
703
712
744
746
763
773
792
805
814
832
868
875
889
899
918
923
941
955
961
969
970
976
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! He aprendido mucho con tu respuesta, elif val == self.val lo puse simplemente por claridad ^^